# CodeIgniter was insensitive about case, and now it is?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, digital-ocean

So basically, I ran XAMPP on my Mac and I built a pretty huge CI website. It worked perfectly.
I then when to make a DigitalOcean account, installed Ubuntu+Lamp, put my database there, and then uploaded my website.

On the very first page, I get this error:
Unable to load the requested file: Login_view.php

I checked, and indeed there was no file called Login_view.php WITH AN UPPERCASE L. But there was a file called login_view.php, that on my XAMPP server it was able to load perfectly well.

I guess this has to do with case sensitivity, and since it's 1:1 the exact same CI project I have on my localhost, I guess it's something to do with the configuration of the server.

How can I configure my Ubuntu server, or the Apache, to be case insensitive with CI?

Comment: [Here's a useful article](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1227827) on this. My suggestion would be to rename your files

Comment: I really can't.. It's to huge of a project to start renaming everything. I'll check out the article

Comment: OSX's file system is case-retentive, but not case-sensitive. Ubuntu is both: retentive AND sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache mod_speling with the CheckCaseOnly directive.

Comment: Actually, I was just thinking I'm not sure whether or not your host will support this or not.

Comment: I googled "apache mod speling" the first result is the [apache documentation for mod speling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html). The second result is [a tutorial describing how to set it up](http://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/apache-web-server/using-the-mod-speling-apache-module).